Is this an appropriate site to ask "applications of blockchain" questions?
I have a question about the feasibility of using blockchain technology in a specific domain, which has nothing to do with crypto currency. Is this the appropriate site to ask such a question? If not, does there exist a stack exchange site I could as it?

Private blockchains and related questions are on-topic on our site. Please take care to show your previous research and ask a specific question, though, as we do close questions that are overly broad.
